# Wordpress widget logic - show on archive, not on single

Tags: php, wordpress

I have inherited a theme that has been built by a third party, which has a post category called "recruitment". The client has requested that a widget only appears on the recruitment category page, and not on the category single page (single.php).

Currently I have the following widget logic:

```
!in_category('branch') && !is_page('shop-online') && !in_category('recruitment') && !is_page('you-are-applying-for-example-job') && !is_page('apply-for-credit-account')
```

I tried removing `!in_category('recruitment')` from the above, however that shows the widget on both category and single pages. Ideally I would like it to just show on the category page. Is there a way I can target the category page alone and still exclude the single pages?

Please shout if you would like me to clarify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong template_tag i.e in_category($category) because it checks if the current post is assigned to the $category.

The correct tag that you should use is is_category($category) which will check if the widget is being displayed on the $category page

Similarly, use is_single($) && in_category($category) to see if the iwdget is being displayed on a single post of category $cateory

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single